# ci_sessions/ci_sessionhv8fep2tl5qj8la2h75lj0nao5eo5pfe): failed to open stream:

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7.4

After moving the server to another IP.
I was unable to login into my system. every time I try to log in its redirect to the same login page and shows this error.

CodeIgniter

```
ci_sessions/ci_sessionhv8fep2tl5qj8la2h75lj0nao5eo5pfe): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: I'm guessing about this but it looks like it is unable to read or write the files in the ci_sessions directory. I hate to say give it 0777 permissions so you can test but it would be the easier way to check it

Answer (score 0):

I tried these commands and it works for me ///

```
ls -ld home
ls -ld dev
rm -r dev/null
ls -ld dev     //no such file or directory

mknod -m 666 /dev/null c13
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).